# HTTP status code with special characters in the URL

Tags: php, javascript, http-headers

I have a little tool written in JavaScript and PHP that takes a list of URLs and checks HTTP status codes for all of them.
I use curl to check the actual status.
It works great as long as I have nice URLs. I'm having a problem with a URL that has **®** in it. My tool returns `404` when I know it should return `301`.

My guess is that this '®' is being converted to something like `%C2` and causes a problem.

I know it can be done because pasting this same URL [here](http://gsitecrawler.com/tools/Server-Status.aspx) returns `301` as it should.

My PHP curl looks like this:

```
        ...
        if (($curl = curl_init()) == false) {
            throw new Exception('curl_init error for url '.$_POST['url'].'.');
        }
        $header[] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5";
        $header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
        $header[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
        $header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300";
        $header[] = "Accept-Charset: iso-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
        $header[] = "Accept-Language: en-US;q=0.5";
        $header[] = "Pragma: ";
        
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $_POST['url']);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
        $Cresponse = curl_exec($curl); // execute the curl command
        $response['callback']['data'] = $http_status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($curl);
        ...
```

I tried to use `urldecode()` but this encodes the whole URL along with `http://` to `http%3A%2F%2F`.

Any idea why this ® is causing problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and `urlencode()` just the `path`, `query` and `fragment`.

Then reassemble the encoded URL and make the request.

```
$url = parse_url ($_POST['url']);
if ($url === FALSE) {
    /* error handling */
}
$encoded_url = $url['scheme'] . "://" .
               $url['host']   .
               urlencode ($url['path])     . "?"   .
               urlencode ($url['query])    . "#"   .
               urlencode ($url['fragment])
```

Answer (score 0):

On the **Javascript** side, you need to escape the url using the `encodeURI` function like this:

```
// results in "http://test.com?var=%C2%AE"
$url = encodeURI("http://test.com?var=®")
```

Then, on the **PHP** side, you need to unescape it with `urldecode` like this before you use it:

```
$url = urldecode($_POST['url']);
```

If this still doesn't work, log the url param to a file or output it and inspect it with your browser console.

Comment: I did as you suggested and Firebug is showing the URL correctly but I'm still getting 404 instead of 301

Answer (score -1):

This depends on how the server expects to receive the URL. URLs may only consist of a subset of ASCII characters. "®" is most certainly not within that subset and needs to be URL-encoded. URL-encoding simply encodes raw bytes in `%xx` pairs. Since "®" can be encoded in several different encodings which encode to different bytes, there's no *one* URL representation of it.

So, `http://example.com/®` is not a valid URL, and there's no single way to make it valid. You should not have to deal with this URL to begin with.

Comment: I know this isn't a valid URL but that's the way someone has created them and I need to check few hundred URLs like this every so often.

Comment: Then you can try something along the lines of @Internet's solution. I'm saying the URLs are already borked and you should fix that problem first, if possible.